# Variable not in scope when using where clause and guard pattern matching

Tags: haskell, scope

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
data Command = Forward Integer
             | Backwards Integer


doSomething givenCommand
 | Forward value <- givenCommand = undefined
 where calculatedValue = sqrt value
```

Let's say the *undefined* line, which would use the `calculatedValue`, is going to be really long and the `calculatedValue` calculation also much longer, so to make the code more readable, I'd like to use a where clause.

The problem is that the variable `value`, specified in the guard pattern match, is not in scope for the where clause.
Is there a way around this, which wouldn't force me to perform the calculation on the guard line ?

Thanks.

Comment: `value` is indeed not in the scope of `where` since it is not said that the given pattern guard will "fire".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`value` is indeed not in the scope of `where` since it is not said that the given pattern guard will "fire". If the pattern fails, then there is no `value`, so that makes not much sense.

You can use a `let … in …` clause here:

```
doSomething givenCommand
    | Forward value <- givenCommand = let calculatedValue = sqrt value in undefined
    | … = …
```

you here however do not need a pattern guard, you can pattern match in the head of the `doSomething` function:

```
doSomething (Forward value) = undefined
    where calculatedValue = sqrt value
doSomething (…) = …
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The actual function, not this illustration one, takes much more arguments, same with the data constructor, so using guards for readability seemed more appropriate to me.